# Setting an IP address as spark.driver.host instead of hostname in Spark?

Tags: linux, networking, apache-spark

I have a problem with declaring an spark.driver.host setting.
Assume that i have an host with a HOSTNAME and binded address `192.168.1.1` (its linux, windows has not this problem at all).

If i set a property `spark.driver.hostname = 192.168.1.1` workers will respond to HOSTNAME, which is really bad, because they don't have DNS with this hostname.

As [this troubleshooting page](https://github.com/databricks/spark-knowledgebase/blob/master/troubleshooting/connectivity_issues.md) says:

> If SPARK_LOCAL_IP is set to an IP address, it will be resolved to a hostname.

And here is a question: how to **NOT** setting this IP address as a hostname?

Answer (score 6):

you can set SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=ip address in your spark environment to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

hostname -f gives your FQDN
add this to /etc/hosts file as

> [your ip address]  [your hostname] on spark nodes

or add your hostname to dns used by your spark nodes

Comment: It is not a good solution because i have to assume that my driver can change it's ip or even worse - i can use different machines to it. Windows still don't have this problem :-(